# Accessing ISIM information on Android

Tags: android

I am writing an IMS application over LTE such that, the MT should take the P-CSCF address it gets while performing an LTE Attach procedure, if it doesn't get any P-CSCF address in the Attach procedure then it should take the P-CSCF address that is present in the ISIM, i.e., the pre-configured one.
I am able to extract the P-CSCF address from the LTE Attach Procedure response, but I am unable to find a mechanism using which i can access the information in ISIM. Is there a set of APIs to access ISIM? If not, how should i go about it?

Thanks,
Mayank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm.. The old answer was in [this thread](http://osdir.com/ml/Android-Developers/2009-08/msg00354.html).